# Inner product identity for Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$, $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ a finite orthonormal set in $H$ for a given index set $I$ and $x\in H$. Also let $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of real numbers.

I cannot understand how to go from line $(1)$ to line $(2)$ in the following:

> $$\begin{align}\tag{1}&||x||^2-2\sum\limits_{i\in I}\alpha_i\langle x | e_i\rangle + \sum\limits_{i\in I}|\alpha_i|^2 \\
> \tag{2}=&||x||^2-\sum\limits_{i\in I}|\langle x|e_i\rangle|^2  + \sum\limits_{i\in I}|\alpha_i-\langle x|e_i\rangle|^2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Hilbert Space is over $\mathbb{R}$, the absolute values are all unnecessary. Grouping the terms in the sums, we have
\begin{align*}(\alpha_i - \langle x | e_i \rangle)^2 - \langle x | e_i \rangle^2 &= \alpha_i^2 + \langle x | e_i \rangle ^2 - 2\alpha_i \langle x|e_i\rangle - \langle x | e_i \rangle^2 \\
&= \alpha_i^2 - 2 \alpha \langle x | e_i \rangle
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes it was the absolute values that were obscuring things for me. I suppose the same result doesn't hold if the field is $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It doesn't work in $\mathbb{C}$. You get a similar result, with $-2\alpha \langle x | e_i \rangle$ replaced by $-\alpha (\langle x | e_i \rangle + \langle e_i | x_i \rangle)$.